# Bootstrap, justify-content not working navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, justify

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light justify-content-start">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Soporte</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav
```

> Im triyng to move just the links bar to the right (not the navbar-brand). Ive tried to put the sentence "justify-content-..." everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You had a `justify-content-start` which I removed and added a new class to `float` the items to `right` in mobile view

let me know if this is what you're looking for...

working **snippet**:

```css
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light ">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://www.akberiqbal.com/favicon.ico"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Inicio<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Servicios</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Soporte</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contacto</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `justify-content-start` from nav tag and keep the `justify-content-end` where it is currently. It should work.